# Why doesnt the condition evaluate to false when not specifically checking for undefined value using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to display the icon based on the prop named count.

What i am trying to do?
I have the Parent and Child components within child component i want to render the icon based on the count prop.

```
render = () => {
const count = 10; //got by http request and its value could be undefined, 0 or anything 
//above 0
return (
    <Wrapper>
        <LeftSide>
            <ContainerComponent>
                <ContentComponent>
                    items_count=10
                    icon_name='add'
                </ContentComponent>
           </ContainerComponent>
       </LeftSide>
       <RightSide>
           <ContainerComponent>
               <ContentComponent>
                   icon_name='delete'
               </ContentComponent>
           </ContainerComponent>
       </RightSide>
   </Wrapper>
```

)

```
const ContentComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({
  icon_name,
  count,
}) => {
    return (
        {condition1 && condition2 && 
            <firstdiv> 
               <seconddiv>
                   <Icon name={icon_name} />
               </seconddiv>
            </firstdiv>
        ))}
    )
}
```

Now here as you see the Icon component display add or delete icons based on the icon_name.

Now i want to add a check to icon add such that this icon should not be displayed when the count is < 1.

I have tried something like below to hide add icon when count <1

```
 if (!condition1 || !condition2) {
  return null;
}

if (icon_name === 'plus') {
  return count !== undefined && //why this check why not count && count=== 0 work
    count === 0 ? null : (
    <firstdiv>
      <seconddiv>
        <Icon name={icon_name} />
      </seconddiv>
    </firstdiv>
  );
} else {
  return (
    <firstdiv>
      <seconddiv>
        <Icon name={icon_name} />
      </seconddiv>
    </firstdiv>
  );
}
```

the above code works...what i am thinking is why should i specifically check

return count !== undefined && count === 0 ? null

and why not adding check like

```
 return count && count === 0 ? null
```

doesnt work. could someone help me understand or fix this if anything wrong. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
count ? null : '' //<-- this will check for 0,false,undefined,null and many more
```

so if you get count 0 and you will try to execute the below line , it will return false first and not check the other condition

```
return count && count === 0 ? null
```

But in below you are checking for a specific type of condition, like if its not undefined and is zero :

```
return count !== undefined && count === 0 ? null
```

---

For more detail, run the below code snippet, hope that will your doubts

```js
const zero = 0;
const und = undefined;
const nl = null;
const fl = false;

console.log(zero ? true : false)
console.log(und ? true : false)
console.log(nl ? true : false)
console.log(fl ? true : false)
```